# NFTable clarification

Tags: debian, nftables

I need some clarification. If I add this rule

```
nft add rule ip filter INPUT ip daddr 127.0.0.1 drop
```

nftables will ignore it and never acknowledge because it is on end of the rules?

Comment: I can't see what exactly is your question. Are you just looking for confirmation?

Comment: I think it will be ignored, because it is not hooked on to a chain.

Comment: Yeah, looking for confirmation if that is true.

Comment: if you have a rule before with something like `iif lo accept` then your rule happens too late. The answer depends on the ruleset, else it's not possible to know for sure. Of course the INPUT chain has to be defined or this will just give an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found answer for my issue.

The stuff is about filters..in nft terminology CHAINS. If I want to add rule, I need to add it to specific chain, otherwise it will ignore my rule and take it as nonsense.

so if I wanted to use this rule `nft add rule ip filter INPUT ip daddr 127.0.0.1 drop`
I already had to have created chain named `INPUT`. Since nft is case sensitive, `INPUT` and `input` can be two differend chains.

Rules are or what I understood should be used right after they are added to Chain.